# Filtering Generic Inquiry via Web Service Endpoint

Tags: acumatica

We have created a Generic Inquiry to show the contents of a Location see attached images.

[GI Tables Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljhFA.png)
[GI Relations Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xif1s.png)

**Conditions**

```
INLocationStatus.QtyOnHand, Is Greater Than, 0
```

**Results Grid**

```
InLocationStatus, InventoryID, INLocationStatus.InventoryID  
InLocationStatus, LocationID, INLocationStatus.LocationID  
InLocationStatus, QtyAvail, InLocationStatus.QtyAvail  
InLocationStatus, QtyOnHand, InLocationStatus.QtyOnHand  
InLocationStatus, SiteID, InLocationStatus.SiteID  
InventoryItem, Descr, InventoryItem.Descr
```

We have added this to our Web Service Endpoint definition and can successfully call the GI with the following code.

```
var temp = c.GetList(new OzLocationDetails {}, false).Cast<OzLocationDetails>();
```

However when we attempt to add a filter condition to this we get an error returned

```
Location = new StringValue { Value = "OZRECV" }
```

The error returned is

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' 
occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 
Server was unable to process request. ---> 
PX.Api.ContractBased.OperationDoesNotSupportValuesException:


Operation does not support values.

at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetList(EntityGateBase gate, 
String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntities,
Boolean ignoreValueFields, PXGraph graph)

at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityGate.GetList(Entity entity, 
Boolean returnFullEntities)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it sounds counterintuitive, but to retrieve the contents of a generic inquiry and retrieve the results, you need to do a `Put()` call. This call will return a single entity, with a Details property containing all the rows returned by the generic inquiry.

Comment: Gabriel, I changed the code to Put and it only returned the first entry not the list of entries.

Comment: Additionally if I do a GetList on the GI it does return all the results, the issue there is we cannot filter them.

Comment: Yes, it does return a single entity - but entity has a Details property which is an array you can iterate on.

Comment: Gabriel, not sure if I am doing anything wrong but it isn't returning a Details property.  I have c.Put(new OzLocationDetails { }) in the C# code and I know that based on the current setup in Acumtica instance there should be at least two rows returned.  However when I look at the results in Visual Studio I don't see any Details property.  Please can you advise what could be causing this?

Comment: @ChrisMarshall, can you show the way you've mapped the GI to the Contract-based Endpoint?

Comment: [WSE Definition 1][1]
[WSE Definition 2][2]

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1hG3N.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/unl6Y.png